# Install vs2015 while i have vs2013 on my PC

Tags: visual-studio

I have installed vs2013 and been using it for months, now due to the restriction of ue4, i have to use vs2015 instead.
Is there a way to do that? Replacing vs2013 with vs2015? If i just uninstall vs2013 and install vs2015, would there be any problem?
Hope you can show me. Much obliged!

Comment: *"If i just uninstall vs2013 and install vs2015, would there be any problem?"* No, not at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install different versions of visual studio side by side without any problem. But You have to install the lower version first then the upper version.

For Example:

Install  visual studio 2013 first then install visual studio 2015. If visual studio 2013 is already installed on your machine then just install visual studio 2015.

Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks, so i can just install 2015 and then uninstall 2013? it is said that visual studio is hard to be completely uninstalled, is that true?

Comment: No need to uninstall vs2013..I have modified the answer for your understand..